# Probleme thread function exection nodejs/redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I have a big problem for execute my program.
we use redis hkey and test if this key exist

```
hgetall tags
"X5"
"6"
"X2"
"7"
```

this is the program :

```
function firstChoiceChannel(){
        var i=0;
        var listRep
        console.log(tags);
        for(var k in tags){
            console.log('@'+k+'|'+tags[k]);
            client.hexists('tags',tags[k],function(err,rep){
                console.log(tags[k]+"=>"+k+' i '+rep)
                if(rep===1){
                         client.hget('tags',tags[k],function(err,rep){
                           console.log('value:'+rep);
                         })
                         console.log('ok');
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

this the execution program in console

```
[ 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X5' ]
@0|X1
@1|X2
@2|X3
@3|X5
X5=>3 i 0
X5=>3 i 1
ok
X5=>3 i 0
X5=>3 i 1
ok
value:7
value:7
```

Why the variable tags[k] in sub-function client.hexists(...function(err,rep){})
is always equal to the last value of table ?

Thanks for your help

vincent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `client.hexists` is asynchronous, so when the callback executes, the for loop has already finished. The easiest way to fix this is to break out the function:

```
function getIfExists(tag) {
  client.hexists('tags', tag, function(err,rep) {
    if(rep===1){
      client.hget('tags',tag,function(err,rep) {
        console.log('value:'+rep);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Also, javascript's `for... in...` syntax is not optimal for arrays.

```
for(var i = 0, len = tags.length; i < len; i++) {
  getIfExists(tags[i]);
}
```

Or you can use `Array.prototype.forEach`:

```
tags.forEach(getIfExists);
```

That said, I'm not sure why you do the `hexists` at all? You could just `hget` it, you'll get `null` or the value.

Comment: how do you think it's function is asynchronous (without testing)?

Comment: Any function which doesn't return it's answer, but instead takes a callback which is invoked with the answer, is (most probably) asynchronous. [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) is a really good control flow library for these kinds of things.